# Convert Standard page blocks to custom VF page

Tags: visualforce

I need to convert a standard visualforce page to a custom VF page.

Are there any easy ways/tricks to do that faster ?

Comment: Not sure there are any "Standard Visualforce Pages" do you mean the Standard View / Edit Pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using apex:detail tag inside a visualforce page as shown below

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
   <apex:detail subject="{!account.ownerId}" relatedList="false" title="false"/> 
</apex:page>
```

> For this example to render properly, you must associate the
>   Visualforce page 
>       with a valid account record in the URL. 
>       For example, if 001D000000IRt53 is the account ID, the resulting URL should be: 
>       https://Salesforce_instance/apex/myPage?id=001D000000IRt53
>       See the Visualforce Developer's Guide Quick Start Tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple app exchange apps that help to generate VF code quickly and worth checking them

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016kP8EAI

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZkUEAU

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000pvkvEAA